# How can I match lines that include a number between X and Y?

Tags: regex, perl

In the large file, I have lines of the form `SIgnal_Catch[0]`, where the number in braces ranges from 0 to 223345. I want to extract the lines where the number is between 2239 and 13569.

I tried this:

```
print "$line" if $line =~ /SIgnal_Catch\[2239-13569]/;
```

but it didn't match the lines I want. I also tried this:

```
print "$line" if $line =~ /SIgnal_Catch\[\d+]/;
```

but it matches too much. How can I do this?
For this specific problem, I cannot use $1 for the range.

Comment: Please try to properly format your question so that others can easily view and understand the code in it.

Comment: It's possible with a regex, but probably easier to use a regex for the string format and capture the number (with `$1` or `$&`, for example), and then compare the number in a seperate if where you define the range there. If you want help with the range in the regex, look here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Comment: Hi mohan, your question was a bit unclear. I think I understand what you're trying to do so I edited it to make it clearer, but please edit again if I misunderstood.

Comment: AnthonH Could you please provide one example if it is possible to find the range without using $1, using plane regex.

Comment: @mohan You would basically have to have strings for all possible numbers, so it would start: `(2239|22[456789]\d|2[3456789]\d{2}...)`, but that would only cover the numbers 2239 to 2999. You would have to add additional statements for the 3000s, 4000s, and so on. Like, I said, it's possible, but so much easier to capture the number and compare it outside the regex.

Comment: @mohan: *"For this specific problem, I cannot use $1 for the range"* Please explain why not. Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @Borodin I wrote a tool myself which extracts this regex from a file and put into some script to find signals and then reassign. it selects only between /../ this and put it in scripts. and this is only one signal out of 1000 So I don't want to fix the tool for this problem.

Comment: @mohan I put my answer with the regex, let me know if this is suitable.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to make regex patterns do too much. You're writing a Perl program, so use Perl

This will do as you ask

```
if ( /SIgnal_Catch\[(\d+)\]/ and $1 >= 2239 and $1 <= 13569 ) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've said you can't use `$1` or `$&`, here is the regex string I made. It works, but it's not pretty:

```
$line =~ /SIgnal_Catch\[\b(2239|22[456789]\d|2[3-9]\d{2}|[3-9]\d{3}|(10|11|12)\d{3}|13[0-4]\d{2}|135[0-6]\d)\b\]/;
```

Like I said in my comments, you basically have to think how the numbers can be represented in a string, and format all the alternatives. I tested this string on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and it works. But if there is even a slight chance that this kind of regex may pop up again in the future, it's worth thinking about whether you can modify the tool (cfr Borodon's response, or my own comments to the original question) rather than just adding more regexes like this one.

N.B.: If you do test it on the regex101 web site, and you have several numbers in the Test String box, don't forget to add the global modifier `g` to the regex, as it will otherwise just find the first.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $line =~ /.*SIgnal_Catch\[([1-9][0-9]{3,4})\].*/ ) {

    if ( $1 >= 2239  &&  $1 <= 13569 ) {
       print $line . "\n";
    }

}
```

Doing what you want with *just* regex would be, um, really hairy.  Try something like the above.

Comment: That matches `1000` to `99999`

Comment: Dan Hydar  Could you please provide one example using plane regex without using $1.

Comment: Borodin -  I matched an easy *close* match with the regular expression, then  tightened the check by comparing the int values.  As long as I was doing a regex *anyway*, I figured I might as well tweak it to disqualify numbers that are *obviously* of range.

1000 < 2239 < 13569 < 99999

Comment: I can't see any way that would be a good idea. The numerical comparison will be extremely fast, and isn't really helped by reducing the range of the value it has to compare. Meanwhile the regex will take rather longer (although insignificantly so).

Comment: Well.... when I've paid attention, it's seemed the overhead of a regular expression engine doesn't increase noticeably with slight changes in complexity (such as looking for a string of \d rather than a length-limited set of chars).  OTOH, adding extra lines of code in a loop might well. Theoretically, it's just an int compare, but all the interpretation behind it  needs to be done. Dunno if Perl tries to be "smart" in that regard.

(A quick test on two versions of  the code verified the speed difference on the version of perl I'm running on my Budget Conscious Linux Box.   YMMV, of course.)

Comment: For good or for ill, I was making the assumption that the values being culled would be a fairly small subset of the values that actually appeared a file (very large - say, millions of lines) .

Now, that being said, it's probably Not  All That Important to do that silly optimization vs having the regular expression being *clearer*.  On that trade-off I plead somewhat guilty.   ;)

Answer (score -1):

As AntonH mentioned you can use the following below:

```
$_ =~ /SIgnal_Catch\[(\d+)\]/;

if ( $1 >= 2239 && $1 <= 13569 )
{
    print $_;
}
```

Your regex above will not work and your match is missing the "[" and "]".

Hope this helps.